# can't add values from field into database Django

Tags: python, django, database

I would like to add data filled into database and output it. But i have no idea where is wrong because my data was't saved into database at all. In views.py, Scholarship is just one scholarship object, LScholarship is displaying all the data in Scholarship. I have similar code for other models and views but i have no idea what i did wrong in here, making the data can't be saved into database. Could anyone please advice me where am i wrong

**add_remove_scholarship.html**

```
 <div align="center" >
    <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validation()"  action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}
    <p>Upload File: {{scholarship.doc}} <input id="doc" type="text" name="doc"> </p>
    <p>Faculty: {{scholarship.faculty}} <input id="faculty" type="text" name="faculty"> </p>
    <p>Opening date: {{scholarship.openDate}} <input id="odate" type="date" name="openDate"> </p>
    <p>Closing date: {{scholarship.closeDate}} <input id="edate" type="text" name="closeDate"> </p>
    <input type="submit" name="AddScholarship" value="Add Scholarship"   >
    </form>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <button id="button" type="button">Delete Selected Scholarship</button>
    <br></br>
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
        <tr align="center">
            <th> Scholarship </th>
            <th> Faculty </th>
            <th> Open Date </th>
            <th> Close Date </th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
        <tr align="center">
            <td>{{item.doc}}</td>
            <td>{{item.faculty}}</td>
            <td>{{item.openDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.closeDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
</form>
```

**models.py**

```
#consists of all the details of the scholarship under the 'Add/Remove 
Scholarship'
class Scholarship(models.Model):
    doc = models.TextField("Doc", max_length=1000)
    faculty = models.TextField("Faculty", max_length=1000)
    openDate = models.DateField("Opening Date", max_length=8)
    closeDate = models.TextField("CLosing Date", max_length=18)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.doc

#consists of all the details of the scholarship under the 'Add/Remove 
Scholarship'
class LScholarship(models.Model):
    scholarship = models.ForeignKey(Scholarship, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def scholarship(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()
    else:
        form = ScholarshipForm()
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', {'form': form})

def lscholarship(request):
    query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
    data={'query_results':query_results}
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)

class ScholarshipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scholarship
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: post your forms

Comment: then what is ScholarshipForm?

Comment: @Exprator i have posted it in the questions under views.py

Comment: @Exprator i have posted it in the questions under views.py

Comment: ok try the answer

Comment: Your view is rendering `add_remove_scholarship.html`, but the template you've shown is `arscholar.html`??

Comment: @FazilZaid it is the same in my code, sorry for confusing u.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two views to render a single template.

You can merge your views into a single one and maybe reduce the logic.
If I have understood your problem correctly you could use your view more like this,

```
def scholarship(request, id=None):
    query_results = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
            scholarship.save()
    else:
        form = ScholarshipForm()
        id = request.GET.get('scholarship')
        query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
    data = {
            'query_results':query_results,
            'form': form,
           }
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)
```

In your template,

```
<div align="center" >
    <form method="POST" onsubmit="return validation()" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.errors }}
        <p>Upload File: {{ form.doc }}</p>
        <p>Faculty: {{ form.faculty }} </p>
        <p>Opening date: {{ form.startDate }} </p>
        <p>Closing date: {{ closeDate }} </p>
        <button type="submit" name="AddUser" value="Add Scholarship" onclick="add()"  >Add Scholarship</button>
    </form>
</div>
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
        <tr align="center">
            <th> Scholarship </th>
            <th> Faculty </th>
            <th> Open Date </th>
            <th> Close Date </th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
        <tr align="center">
            <td>{{item.doc}}</td>
            <td>{{item.faculty}}</td>
            <td>{{item.openDate}}</td>
            <td>{{item.closeDate}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: it is working now, but when i have selected the "Add" button, the data to be shown in the table below will disappear, i need to refresh the page only the data will be shown. Besides that, can i remove the LScholarship class inside my models.py ? And also, how can i make the database to be having only one UNIQUE doc file in the database ? I have tried to make the doc as primary_key=True, but i will receive error saying: "django.db.utils.IntegrityError"